CIJ: creating contact point consent
With Customer Insight journeys,
I am creating via SSIS using Kingswaysoft contact point consent, sometimes I got this message
{"code":"0x80040265",
"message":"Contact point consent with the same value already exists"}

It is false, because no consent with same emailaddress exists.
It does work for 200 contacts, but more than 200 it starts giving me the error for some records.
Of course I empty the contact point consent table before each test.

I am using Kingswaysoft, so problem come from the parameter "Use Homogeneous Batch Operation Messages".
More explanation from Kingswaysoft:

While the feature provides some incredible performance improvement, it also comes with some constraints that should be taken into consideration when deciding whether and how to use it.


The most important issue with the new batch operation is, that the new batch message has a different error handling behavior. To be more specific, there is no partial batch process available as we do in the traditional ExecuteMultiple message. In other words, when you submit a batch (CreateMultiple, UpdateMultiple, or DeleteMultiple), if there is one record failing in the batch due to any reason (such as data type or data length/size overflow errors), then the entire batch will fail. There isn't a ContinueOnError option like we do in the ExecuteMultiple message. If you have the trust that your input data is always valid for writing to the target entity, then you are encouraged to leverage the new feature.

Source: More info here

In this case, could you please reach out to our KingswaySoft Technical Support team at www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us, so we can have a closer look at this behavior. You may provide the full error message as text, as well as the current configuration you have within the General Page of the component causing the behavior, so our team can examine it more closely. Thank you.
